# CI HMVC: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::module()

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Just started trying out the CI 3 HMVC framework by jlamim (original CI 2 HMVC by wiredesignz): https://github.com/jlamim/ci3-hmvc

Getting Call to undefined method CI_Loader::module()

Here is the referenced code

```
$data['top_content']['view'] = $this->load->module($module['name']);
```

Here is the controller code for the module it's calling

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class BatchList extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->load->view('BatchList', NULL, TRUE);
    }
}
```

I've read and reread the readme for this version of the framework and I don't know why it won't recognize this method. I tried the alternative Modules::load() and it does not recognize the Modules class.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Codeigniter 2 HMVC does not work on CI3 use the current version of hmvc https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc also when you use current version of hmvc you may need to add this code https://pastebin.com/vNUhJCss

Comment: This did it, thanks! Side questions, I thought $this->load->module() is equivalent to Modules::run(). When i use $this->load->module() I get an error saying Object of Class MY_Loader could not be converted to a string.